# Besides Larloch, what other prominent Realms wizards know how to make a mythallar?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, forgotten-realms, lore

Being an active Sorcerer-King of Netheril, [Larloch](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Larloch) probably still has the knowledge (if not the means) of crafting a [mythallar](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Mythallar).

There's [Rhaugilath](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Rhaugilath) who is also a sorcerer-king, but since he is under Larloch's dominion, it is the same as Larloch.

The Shadovar are all dead, so [Telamont Tanthul](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Telamont_Tanthul) (another Sorcerer-King) is gone.

So, outside Larloch's sphere of influence, is there any active Realms wizard that knows how to make a mythallar?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure I'd call him "active" but Ioulaum would know how to make one, being the Archmage that invented the Mythallar.

Last [I read he had transferred his consciousness into an undead elder brain](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Ioulaum) and he may have a steep price for giving out this information.

Comment: Hi cbwjm, and welcome to the site! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. This answer would be improved by citing where it is we can find this information, so that others can independently verify whether this is correct. Also, when you reach 20 rep, you can join us in [chat].

Comment: @doppelgreener i will add a wiki link to the answer, but that is a very good first post. +1'd

Answer (score 2):

The Halruaans are decendants of the Netherese. Given that they are also a magocracy ruled by 400+ high-level wizards, and that they employ magic, such as flying skyships, at a level unlike any other society in Faerûn, it is a good bet that some of the Halruaans might know of the secrets of building mythallars.

I am not sure what happened to him during the Spellplague and the Second Sundering, but **Raumark**, the sorcerer-king who led the Netherese down to the Shining South and found Halruaa, was still alive and kicking (in the hallucinations of Elminster?) in the book *Temptation of Elminster*. According to 3.5e sourcebook *Lost Empires of Faerûn* (LEoF), Raumark was the Archwizard of Hlondath, one of the three flying cities that the reincarnated Mystra could save following Karsus's Folly.

LEoF has a section titled "Keepers of the Past" (pg 100-102). It first mentions a number Netherese characters who are still around: Aumvor the Undying, several members of the Grand Cabal, Telamont Tanthul. Then details are provided for a couple of other Netheril survivors who might be willing to share information with others: **Ioulaum** (as an undead elder brain); **Rhaugilath**; the ghost sorceress **Lady Saharel** ("a leading member of the High Mages of Netheril"); and the sarrukh lich **Arthindol**, who used to be known as the Terraseer in ancient Netheril. All of these archwizards have been around for a long time (in Arthindol's case, for more than 30 thousand years), so it would be reasonable to assume that they must have weathered the weird D&D4e century, as well. Finally, one of the greatest storehouses of Netheril's lost lore, **The Library of Raumark**, is described to be at Mount Talath in Halruaa.